# Easiest way to make disabled button look disabled with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

When I use .prop('disabled',true) to disable a button, it works, but the button does not look disabled. I remember in the old days when I used .attr('disabled','disabled') to disable buttons, they would become more visibly disabled, i.e. the text would be greyed out or something so the user wouldn't try to click. Now I think the button border fades a bit but the text is not.

What's the easiest way to get the old behavior back? I am lazy and don't want to write one line of code to disable the button and another to make it look disabled - I want to get both effects in a single command if possible. Should I use a different element other than a button? A different method of disabling?

I made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ak2MG/. Here's the code.

HTML:

```
<button type='button' id='mybutton'>Click Me</button>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#mybutton').click( function() {
    $('#mydiv').append("<p>Button was clicked.</p>");
    $('#mybutton').prop('disabled',true); } );
```

Answer (score 14):

Or change the opacity of the button

```
$('#mybutton').click( function() {
    $('#mydiv').append("<p>Button was clicked.</p>");
    $('#mybutton').prop('disabled',true).css('opacity',0.5);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ak2MG/3/)

Answer (score 8):

I would add a `disabled` class to the button.

This lets you control the styling from CSS instead of javascript so all of your styling is in one place (where it should be).

Demo: **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryanwinchester/VTERq/)**

**HTML**

```
<button type='button' id='mybutton'>Click Me</button>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#mybutton').click( function() {
    $('#mydiv').append("<p>Button was clicked.</p>");
    $('#mybutton').prop('disabled',true).addClass('disabled');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.disabled {
    color: #999;
}
```

Comment: You can also daisy chain into `$('#mybutton').css('color', "#999").prop('disabled', true);`

Answer (score 4):

it is pretty simple, just change the text style

```
$('#mybutton').click( function() {
    $('#mydiv').append("<p>Button was clicked.</p>");
    my_button_disable(this);
});

function my_button_disable(btn) {
    $(btn).prop('disabled',true);
    $(btn).css('color', 'lightgray');
    // put whatever else you want here
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ak2MG/6/

Answer (score 4):

Simplest - Add a state in CSS
Target it with CSS to change the style,
importantly the pointer-events: none will make it unresponsive. :

```
    button:disabled {
        background: #F5F5F5;
        color : #C3C3C3;
       cursor:none;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The change from attr() to prop() was only to the jQuery API and has nothing to do with any difference you are observing in the style of a disabled button.

A disabled button's style is decided by the browser.  The fiddle you provided looks very "disabled" in Google Chrome (Version 33.0.1750.154 m).  If you'd like to alter the style of a disabled button to your liking, I recommend adding a class OR styling based on attribute

```
button[disabled],
button.disabled {
    color: #999;
    background: #DDD;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```