# Add alert text on disabled button click

Tags: javascript, html

I have this next button disabled that is activated when all fields are filled, how can I add an error text if it is clicked before filling all fields.

```js
const b = document.getElementById('button');
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener("input", displayButton);
})

function showButton() {
  const name = document.getElementById('name').value
  const last_name = document.getElementById('last_name').value

  if (name.length > 0 && last_name.length > 0) {
    b.disabled = false
  } else {
    b.disabled = true
  }
}

showButton();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="NAME">
<input type="text" id="last_name" placeholder="LAST NAME">
<button id="button" disabled>Next</button>
<span id="error_msg"></span>
```

Comment: You can not click on a disabled element... Why don't you just use form with validation.... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#the_required_attribute

Comment: Another option: don't disable the button. You can use CSS to shade it so it looks like it's disabled, but the click listener will still run and you can display an alert.

Comment: @Barmar Your idea makes sense, how do I achieve that in my code? please help

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646904/easiest-way-to-make-disabled-button-look-disabled-with-jquery for how you can use CSS to make a button look disabled when you add a `disabled` class to it.

Comment: Since you can't click a disabled element anyway, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @ScottMarcus They want to allow clicking on it so they can display an error alert.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but that seems circular. If you show an alert that says you can't click this yet because you haven 't filled out the inputs, then just don't enable it until the inputs have content.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The problem with that is it's just silent when you try to click. They may feel that it's better to give an explicit "You need to fill in all fields first" error.

Comment: @Barmar I guess that would be a useful feature 25 years ago when people were still getting used how filling out forms on the web works. This just seems like a solution in search of a problem. How about hiding the button until the fields are completed? Then, there's nothing to try to click on until clicking is appropriate. Or as was mentioned, why not just use `required` and let the built in HTML5 form validation do its thing?

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason that the [native HTML5 form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) behavior and the CSS3 validation pseudo-classes aren't suitable for you?

No JavaScript needed unless you want to customize the messages and/or add additional programmatic validation logic.

```css
input:invalid { background:#FBDCD5; }
input:valid { background:#E7FBD5; }
```

```html
<form>
  <input  placeholder="NAME" required>
  <input  placeholder="LAST NAME" required> 
  <button>Next</button>
</form>
```

And if you'd like to customize the error message, you can leverage the HTML Form Validity API (link above):

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
document.querySelector("form > button").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  inputs.forEach(function(input){
    if (input.validity.valueMissing) {
      input.setCustomValidity("You must type someting in here!");
    } else {
      input.setCustomValidity("");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input:invalid { background:#FBDCD5; }
input:valid { background:#E7FBD5; }
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input  placeholder="NAME" required>
  <input  placeholder="LAST NAME" required> 
  <button>Next</button>
</form>
```